# class Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipient : setter of properties AddressEntry.Name and AddressEntry.Address has no effect

Tags: c#, .net, outlook

Using msvs 2008/.net 3.5/Outlook 2007  I ran into the following problem :
while trying to create and add a new Recipient to an existing MailItem instance :

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
Recipient rcp = mail.Recipients.Add("foo@bar.com");
if (rcp.Resolve())
{
    rcp.AddressEntry.Name = "Foo";
}
```

No compilation error or warning occured, no exception is thrown, but after assignment of property 'Name', its value remains the same ('foo@bar.com'). Shouldn't it be "foo" ?
(this property is extensively documented as 'read/write')

Does anyone has any indication on the reason for this ?
More generally (I am new to .net) : is it a common C# 'feature' that setters may silently fail ?
Thanks for any advice!

**Alternate solution :**
This syntax :

```
Recipient rcp = mail.Recipients.Add("Foo foo@bar.com")
```

instanciates a `Recipient` object where :

```
rcp.AddressEntry.Name == "Foo"
rcp.AddressEntry.Address == "foo@bar.com"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For your outlook question**
While you are correct that the `Name` property on [`AddressEntry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms528289%28v=EXCHG.10%29.aspx) is read/write, it does specify that it should not be modified after resolved, and can be set [in order to lookup](http://help.lockergnome.com/office/AddressEntry--ftopict978379.html).  I would not be surprised if it has some guards in the setter.  You can also [reference this thread](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/Outlook-Redemption/message/387) which describes the same problem and has a response with some more information stating to Change the `Recipient.Name`, or to create a new `AddressEntry` and assign it.

**For your C# property question**
In .net (and COM as well - outlook interop is done through COM), a property is really a method with different syntax.

Normally in c#, you would [define a property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04.aspx) like such:

```
private string _name;
public string Name 
{
   get{ return _name;}
   set{ _name = value;}
}
```

If the `AddressEntry.Name` was defined like this, then yes, you would expect to get "Foo" back right after you set it.

But nothing prevents it from being declared:

```
private string _name;
public string Name 
{
   get{ return _name;}
   set
   { 
      if( ValidateName(value))
      {
         _name = value;
      }
   }
}
```

Note that in this case, the *backing field* (`_name`) is not set unless the `ValidateName` method returns true.   So if you set the name property and it wasn't valid, asking for the value of the name property would not show your updates.

So I wouldn't say they silently "fail" - normal practice would be to expose the problem in some documented way (IDataErrorInfo, an exception, etc) - but more that a property set is not at all like setting a variable's value.  Instead, it's like calling a method that is *assumed* to set a value.

Comment: You are right, this behavior for property Name was documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms528289%28v=EXCHG.10%29.aspx (section 'remarks').  
Things are much clearer now. Thanks Philip!